# Can't Set Required selectOneChoice

Tags: java, oracle-adf

In my fragment i have

```
<af:selectOneChoice value="#{pageFlowScope.loanPurposeBean.loanPurpose.levelPurpose}" contentStyle="width:150px"
    autoSubmit="true" readOnly="#{pageFlowScope.loanPurposeBean.activity=='edit'}"
                      required="true" label="Cấp mục đích vay" id="soc1"
                      valueChangeListener="#{pageFlowScope.loanPurposeBean.valueChangeLevel}">
    <af:selectItem label="1" value="1" id="si10"/>
    <af:selectItem label="2" value="2" id="si5"/>
    <af:selectItem label="3" value="3" id="si6"/>
    <af:selectItem label="4" value="4" id="si3"/>
    <af:selectItem label="5" value="5" id="si9"/>
    <af:selectItem label="6" value="6" id="si8"/>
    <af:selectItem label="7" value="7" id="si4"/>
    <af:selectItem label="8" value="8" id="si1"/>
    <af:selectItem label="9" value="9" id="si2"/>
    <af:selectItem label="10" value="10" id="si7"/>
  </af:selectOneChoice>

  <af:selectOneChoice value="#{pageFlowScope.loanPurposeBean.loanPurpose.loanPurposeParent}"
                      immediate="true"
                      binding="#{pageFlowScope.loanPurposeBean.socLoanPurposeParent}" contentStyle="width:150px"
                       partialTriggers="soc1" readOnly="#{pageFlowScope.loanPurposeBean.activity=='edit'}"
                      label="Mã cha mục đích vay" id="soc2">
    <f:selectItems value="#{pageFlowScope.loanPurposeBean.loanPurposeByLevel}"
                   id="si12"/>
  </af:selectOneChoice>
```

and My Bean

```
public void valueChangeLevel(ValueChangeEvent valueChangeEvent) {
    level = (Integer)valueChangeEvent.getNewValue();
    System.out.println("New value level: " + level);
    if (level > 1) {
        socLoanPurposeParent.setDisabled(false);
        socLoanPurposeParent.setRequired(true);
    } else {
        socLoanPurposeParent.setDisabled(true);
        socLoanPurposeParent.setValue("");
    }
    if (level > 0) {
        level = level - 1;
    }
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(socLoanPurposeParent);

}
```

if i select level with value > 1, i set required = true then i select level with value = 1 and set required = false but i still get validation from selectonechoice soc2

Comment: Issue is that you are doing validation on server side. It should be handled on client side itself through javascript.You can easily find javascrip code to achieve same. Unleass you have very specific reason you should do it in clientside only.
I do not have very much idea on oracle-adf so my advice may not be relevent to you.

Answer (score 0):

do following
this.getsoc2().setRequired(true);